# Pandas JSON_Normalize only specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a nested JSON structure which I need to flatten. On using JSON normalize it flattens all the keys. But, I want to flatten specific keys while preserving the other keys nested. How to achieve this with JSON normalize. The detail description of what I am trying to do is as follows.

The JSON data that looks something like this

```
data = {"Attachment":[{"url":"URL001", "type":"pdf"}, 
                      {"url":"URL002", "type":"pdf"}],
        "Image":{"url":"URL001", "type":"png"},
        "Lookup":{"ProductName":"Item001", "ProductId":"001"}}
```

On running the following snippet it flattens both`Image` and `Lookup` field.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data)
df.to_json(orient="records")
```

The output looks something like,

```
Attachment     Image.URL   Image.Type  Lookup.ProductName Lookup.ProductId
[{...}, {...}]    URL001     png              Item001                 001
```

But I don't want to flatten the `Image` key and preserve it as it is.

The expected Output looks like

```
Attachment           Image             Lookup.ProductName Lookup.ProductId
[{...}, {...}]       {"url":...,}      Item001                 001
```

Is there a way to achieve this using JSON normalize.

Answer (score 1):

How about you just separate `data` in to two separate dictionaries. Perform 2 different transform operations and then join the respective dataframes:

```
data1 = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if k!='Image'}
data2 = {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if k=='Image'}
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data1).join(pd.DataFrame([data2]))
```

Comment: No that would be costly also its not just two fields. I have a huge dictionary to work with.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to flatten one field, but not the others at the same level. Therefore, you can normalize the same json twice, but specifying on which level using `max_level` in `pd.json_normalize` function and then joining them together after dropping columns that you don't need.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Attachment":[{"url":"URL001", "type":"pdf"}, 
                      {"url":"URL002", "type":"pdf"}],
        "Image":{"url":"URL001", "type":"png"},
        "Lookup":{"ProductName":"Item001", "ProductId":"001"}}

df_level0 = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=0).drop(columns=['Lookup', 'Attachment'])
df_level1 = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=1)
df_level1 = df_level1.loc[:,~df_level1.columns.str.startswith('Image')]
df = pd.concat([df_level0, df_level1], axis=1)
```

gives you the expected output